# Changing Play Store default language and/or country

Tags: google-play-store, languages

I bought a Samsung S4 here in the Philippines but the default language in the Play Store is Korean. Also, the prices of the apps for sale are in Won (Korean currency). How do I change the language to English? And how can I see the app prices in Philippine Peso? Please help me!

Comment: Can you also try the solutions here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26809/is-it-a-way-to-turn-off-translation-in-google-play

Answer (score 1):

`System settings > My device > Language and keyboard > Language`.

Note: I also have an S4, and also from Philippines.

Comment: Hello @geffchang. I went to the Language and Keyboard option and it's already in English. :( My Play Store's still in Korean :(

Comment: @user33951 Where did you buy the phone? From Globe, Smart, or a cellphone shop?

Comment: @user33951 Does it have "English (Philippines)"?

Comment: I got it from Globe. Yes, it does have English (Philippines) and that's the one I chose.

Comment: @user33951 That's weird. Are you using any proxy, or bypassing Globe somehow? The phone is probably detecting you are on a Korean IP address.