# Problems with changing the default country in Google Play Store

Tags: google-play-store, localization

I need help regarding changing my country on the Google Play Store. I tried everything from hard resetting my phone to changing all the details in the settings but it didn't work. I changed all my Google Wallet details to the US address, even added a US-based payment method, set the US address and payment method as default, then I tried clearing the cache, purchasing an app using the new payment method. I even did another hard reset, but unfortunately for me, nothing has worked so far.

I would be really grateful if you guys could offer me some help regarding this problem.

Please don't redirect me here: [How do I change the Google Play country?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42347/how-do-i-change-the-google-play-country)

I tried that already but doesn't work for me.

Unfortunately I also can't root my device (Xperia Z Ultra) since root is not yet available for it and I am using a Mac.

Comment: See this => http://android.stackexchange.com/q/26809/23379

Comment: sorry that didn't solve it either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys, so after nearly a whole day spent searching for ways to make this work I have finally, finally made it. 
So here's what made it work for me. I did everything mentioned in my original post, then I gave up with my google ID and made a new US based google account. Removed the old google ID from my device, did another hard reset and then logged in with my new ID. The US play store worked fine for a while with Tunnelbear for vpn, but then it went back to my local play store, and then started to crash repeatedly until it refused to open anymore. 
I was then fed up and put back my old google ID and removed the new one that I had just created, and guess what. Tada! It logged me into the US play store without any trouble. No need for vpn or any other fix. It's been working fine since, and fingers crossed it will forever.

So, what you have to do is log out of your current google ID, log in from another (new) one, and then remove the new ID and log back in from your old google ID.
Make sure that before logging in with the new ID, update all your google wallet and google account details with US address, payment and phone number on your old ID.

Hope this was clear.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately you can't do it in google play.but can login to your google account, and there you click on edit next to your email id and here you can see the option to edit information in the country field. Now you can change your country whatever you want.
but if this won't help you and want to access the playstore apps that have a **country restriction**, you can use apps like **Hideman** [hideman VPN playstore link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.hideman)  to access play store apps via their servers at USA and you can actually download them.

Comment: I tried with the tunnelbear before, but a vpn solution is not what I'm looking for. I've posted my complete fix here as well.

Answer (score 0):

When I faced similar issue I followed the following procedure to clear the foreign language and restored my local language back:

Go to App Manager -- open play store -- clear cache

Answer (score 0):

Google is making it easier, as reported today, to change the country to a different one. From [Android Police](https://www.androidpolice.com/2018/03/20/now-little-bit-easier-change-country-google-play-store/) on 2018/03/20:

> Now, Google appears to be taking one teeny tiny step toward making the switch easier for some people. If your Play Store country is set to country A (whether you lived there or, uhm, fooled Google into thinking you did because you made a purchase with a valid payment method and to a valid shipping address in that country), and the Play Store detects that you've moved to country B (likely based on your IP address), you'll get a new option in the Account settings: Country and profiles. There you'll see which country your Store account is on and an option to quickly switch to the new country - provided you have a valid payment method there.

There are some caveats to this:

> Keep in mind that this Country and profiles option won't be there for everyone and won't let you switch to any country you want. It appears to only show up when it detects a discrepancy between your setting and your IP address.