# can't install app, because it's not supported in my country/area

Tags: applications, google-play-store, installation, localization

I recently moved to another country and i would like to install bank appliation for my bank account in this country.
however Play Store says i can't do that, because it's not available in my country (i guess it thinks i'm still in a previous country)

how to 'switch' to actual region/country ?

Comment: @wbogacz Nope. OP doesn't want to circumvent regional restrictions. He's obviously moved to another country, and Play got stuck with his old one. So that would be a duplicate of: [How do I change the Google Play country?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/42347/16575) Also see: [Problems with changing the default country in Google Play Store](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/50878/16575)