# Can't install country-restricted app even if I'm physically in this country

Tags: google-play-store

I am trying to install this banking app from Google Play: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.ing.ingmobile

This app is allowed to be installed only by users in Poland. My Google account was created in Brazil, but I am in Poland since almost 7 months, so I should be allowed to install this app.

On Google Play, it says: `This app is incompatible with all of your devices.`, further more, on my phone's tooltip, it reads: `This item cannot be installed on your device's country.`.

That is very problematic, as this device was bought in Poland, is using a Polish SIM card and most importantly, it **is** physically in Poland, so how can it not be compatible?

How can I force-install this app on my device? It is a Sony Xperia Z Ultra, rooted and flashed with CM12.1.

Comment: Have you tried installing the app from the [web version of the Play store](https://play.google.com) What does it display?

Comment: Yes, those messages I quoted are from the Web version. In fact I could only find the app through a Google search, because it doesn't show up for me on mobile neither by searching directly in the Web version.

Comment: Are you using a Polish billing address/payment method on your account? It may be checking that, even if the app is free, to determine the "location" of your account.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. I have Brazilian and Polish credit cards added to my Wallet, but the default card is the Brazilian. I'll try to set it to the Polish card and see what happens.

Comment: @eldarerathis Still no luck, I've set the Polish card as default payment method and my address in Poland as default delivery address, but I still can't install this app.

Comment: On the web version of Google Play, I switched to another Google account on the top right menu, and for some reason the App is available to this account.

Comment: Our [google-play-store tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/google-play-store/info) leads you to the answers on this: [How do I change the Google Play country?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/42347/16575) / [Problems with changing the default country in Google Play Store](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/50878/16575) match your case, and there's also [How can I circumvent regional restrictions in Google's Play Store?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/12538/16575)

Comment: I'd like to add here the reason why I couldn't change my Google Account's country: I have apps for sale on Google Play, thus I have a Google Merchant account automatically configured, and thus I'm not allowed to change my Google's account country.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Polish credit or debit card to your Google Wallet account and remove any other cards.