# Applications in Play Store cannot be downloaded

Tags: google-play-store, google-account, localization

I have moved to Australia from India. My Google Play Store doesn't allow me to download Australian applications. It tells me that the application is not available in my country, but I am in Australia, so why am I not allowed to download? The application I'm trying to download is free of cost. Please help.

Comment: By 'shifted' what do you mean? You traveled from india to australia, or you switched the country associated to your google account from india to australia?

Comment: To make Playstore aware you're moved needs a few steps to perform. Please see [How do I change the Google Play country?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/42347/16575) and also [Problems with changing the default country in Google Play Store](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/50878/16575) (taken from our [google-play-store tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/google-play-store/info): our tag-wikis often hold useful details on frequent issues).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using your mobile data you still have a india ip address. try downloading on wifi.

Comment: Huh? If OP moved to Australia, why should the device get an Indian IP on mobile data? Even if on roaming (and not with a local contract), the device would use a local provider and thus get an Australian IP.

Comment: If he doesnt have a Aussie Sim card he would still have a India sim which would give a india ip address.

Comment: Nope, it wouldn't. If he's in Down Under, his SIM couldn't reach out to an Indian cell to book into. It would use the [roaming](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/roaming/info) feature and book into an Aussie cell – which provides Aussie IPs, not Indian ones. From the linked tag-wiki: *done by using a communication terminal or else just by using the subscriber identity **in the visited network*** (emphasis mine). For additional details, also see the corresponding [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roaming).