# Any way to stop ridiculous translations in Google PlayStore?

Tags: google-play-store, localization

Most of the translations are nonsense in Google Playstore. Looks stupid, amateurish and most of all they are annoying.

Words by words meaning nothing!  My mother language is finnish and Im using finnish keyboard layout/language settings on my devices and not going to change them. I dont want to change my account info nor my language settings to english either.

I just want to see get rid of these stupid autotranslated infos in Playstore.

Most of them are just rubbish "A man has a spruce childish cat and his dock the bank a dog is letting manipulate processor and litter more green guy. Screen broken man shooting wife borrowed a child desktop. AMAZING APP! 95/100 stars!" - that sentence can be anything...

Im quessing im not wrong if I say that 99% means nothing when autotranslated. Only few infos are correct.

I cant believe that you cannot turn off the translation in Playstore!?

Comment: AFAIK you can't. It's up to the dev when the app is uploaded to decide whether its description should be auto-translated to languages he cannot provide his own description for.

Comment: Then it is better to leave the language as it is. Why even bother translating info when the app isnt translated at all? Playstore was better, now it is only full of rubbish translations! All this looks so amateurish and childish that it makes me thinking about changing ecosystem when buying a new device. Are we really living a year 2013 with Android? Looks more like living with first steps of a baby.

Comment: While I totally agree (Playstore became absolutely unusable for me when it converted to "Tile-Store" this summer: if I want to see tiles, I prefer my bathroom), this is nothing we here at ASE can deal with. We have no influence on Google, nor on its store, neither on all those devs deciding to have those stupid machine-translations forced upon us. Nor can we offer any other work-around but "use another one" (hint: [AppBrain](http://www.appbrain.com/) is an alternative frontend to Google Play which *I personally* favour a lot).

Comment: One thing you can do is to poke at the devs - if they get push back from the auto-translations, then you can perhaps get them to stop using the feature.

Comment: This is not entirely up to the devs anymore. If the devs haven't translated their app themselves then Google Play automatically(!) uses auto-translations, which is insane! This cannot be switched off. The devs cannot do anything about this except provide real translations. And nobody is going to translate his app to tens of languages. Of course one hack is to copy-paste the English texts to all other languages as "translations".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to turn off translation in Google Play](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26809/is-there-a-way-to-turn-off-translation-in-google-play)

Answer (score 7):

You can force the language that app descriptions are shown in on the web version of the Play Store by changing the language code in the link. This is shown in the URL as `hl=language`, for example `hl=en` for English, `hl=fi` for Finnish or `hl=fr` for French.

So for example, to see an English description for the GMail app you'd got to this link:

[`https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gm&hl=en`](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gm&hl=en)

Or in Finnish:

[`https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gm&hl=fi`](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gm&hl=fi)

Or to see it in French go here:

[`https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gm&hl=fr`](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gm&hl=fr)

Or in German go here:

[`https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gm&hl=de`](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gm&hl=de)

You'll see that all that's changed between those is the `&hl=` bit at the end of the link, yet the whole Play Store page including the description and reviews has changed to the relevant language.

Comment: I use the same workaround as you, I am adding &hl=en to the end of link all the time. It is a pity that previous version web Play Store has a handy pulldown menu with other languages and it is missing in the latest version. I asked myself: Why it is everything so dumbed now?

Comment: @jis Sometimes I generally ask myself whether features are being permanently removed, instead of added, to everything I use. Maybe it's just perception bias.

Answer (score 1):

Very old post, but maybe someone still search for an answer. You can change language for Play Store with Xposed Framework Module: App Settings.

Comment: 1) OP didn't say his/her device is rooted and Xposed framework installed, so your answer has assumed it; it is not that assumption is a bad thing but it should be mentioned, 2) A hyperlink to the said module along with a brief description is always helpful since why should one bothers checking this app on some  page then to other page if I can know it right here. Please [edit](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/111170/edit).