# Stop Google Play app from translating

Tags: google-play-store, 7.0-nougat, localization, 7.1-nougat

Related:

- [Is there a way to turn off translation in Google Play](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26809)
- [Any way to stop ridiculous translations in Google PlayStore?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/56260)

I have an exactly the same goal as the above questions, but my situation is a bit different from above.

- I don't want to change my system language (Chinese)
- [Changing Language Settings](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32047) for my Google account doesn't work. It does not affect the user interface of Play Store app on my phone.
- Tried [App Settings](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.mods.appsettings), but it doesn't work at all. Maybe Xposed for N is too new.

I'm using a OnePlus 5 with stock ROM (very similar to AOSP).